# How to use an Angular JS model Value in php variable

Tags: php, angularjs

```
<?php 
    $name = "{{t_33}}";
    $y=$name;
    for($i=$y;$i<24;$i++) { ?>
        <li>
            <a class="<?php 
                    if (($i>0 and $i<4) || ($i>20 and $i<24)) echo 'dark';
                    else if (($i>3 and $i<8)|| ($i>16 and $i<21)) echo 'light';
                    else if ($i>7 and $i<17) echo ''; ?>" 
                href="#">
                <?php echo $i; ?>
            </a> 
            <?php if($i==1) { ?> 
                <h4>{{day}}</h4> 
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
```

The issue is that I am getting the value in `$name` but when I assign it in `$y` and try to use it in for loop the page goes blank. Please help.

Comment: Always proper indent your code in order to be able to revisit it and debug it.

Comment: i will keep it in mind. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is with order of processing your code. You should know that php is interpreted on server side and javascript is procesed on client side. 
Now when your angular is code running, php functions are already processed. (I'm simplyfing here ofc.)

Comment: But when the variable name is getting the value why not it is working in the loop. I mean both of them are php variables so 1 is working and not the other.

Comment: $y is now string... Not integer, maybe this is a cause. Check if you hardcode number there...